# Parse a string into various values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Assuming you have the string below, how would you recommend parsing it out into its various values?  Each "record" ends with a break tag.  The first value is the event name, the second between the parentheses is the account number, next is the ticket quantity and lastly is the total price paid.

```
Education Luncheon (501-2620) - 2 - $110<br>Womens Breakfast (512-2620) - 2 - $80<br>Friday Luncheon (502-26200) - 2 - 110<br>
```

Comment: If this is to be used in another application like .net, java, whatever, I suggest doing the parsing in the application code as opposed to sql.

Comment: Gonna be used in ColdFusion, was hoping to do in SQL but I'll dust off my CF skills and see if that will work.

Comment: You can also take a look at CLR Function and/or User-defined function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to so say a direct query with use of `XML` parsing and `PARSENAME` and `REPLACE` functions without using any `UDF`:

Suppose this string:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)='Education Luncheon (501-2620) - 2 - $110<br>Womens Breakfast (512-2620) - 2 - $80<br>Friday Luncheon (502-26200) - 2 - 110<br>'
```

now just with converting that string to `XML` and parsing it inside a `cte` and finally using the mentioned string functions:

```
   ;WITH cte AS(   
      SELECT Value = tbl.fld.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')            
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT 
            v = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
                + REPLACE(@str, '<br>' , '</i><i>') 
                + '</i>')
      ) AS a 
      CROSS APPLY v.nodes('i') AS tbl(fld)
      WHERE tbl.fld.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') IS NOT NULL
    )
    SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(Value ,'(','.'),2) AS [Event],
           PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(Value ,'(','.') ,')','.'),2)AS AccNumber,
           PARSENAME(REPLACE(Value ,'-','.'),2) AS Qty ,
           PARSENAME(REPLACE(Value ,'-','.'),1) AS Price         
    FROM cte
```

We will get this Result:

```
|               Event | AccNumber | Qty | Price |
|---------------------|-----------|-----|-------|
| Education Luncheon  |  501-2620 |  2  |  $110 |
|   Womens Breakfast  |  512-2620 |  2  |   $80 |
|    Friday Luncheon  | 502-26200 |  2  |   110 |
```

Comment: Had to make a couple tweaks, but otherwise this works pretty well with a reasonable amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

First Create a Split function. then use the following query .

### Split Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
-- Id column can be commented out, not required for sql splitting string
  id int identity(1,1), -- I use this column for numbering splitted parts
  val nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select
    r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
GO
```

### Test Data & Query

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(1000) = 'Education Luncheon (501-2620) - 2 - $110<br>Womens Breakfast (512-2620) - 2 - $80<br>Friday Luncheon (502-26200) - 2 - 110<br>'


SELECT LEFT(val , CHARINDEX('(', Val) -1 ) AS EventName  
      ,REPLACE( REPLACE(
           SUBSTRING(Val , CHARINDEX('(', Val) , LEN(Val) -  CHARINDEX(')', Val))
             ,'(',''),')','') AS AccountNumber
      ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Val, 
                CHARINDEX(') -', Val) +2,  LEN(Val) - CHARINDEX(') -', Val) 
              - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val)))
              ,'-','') AS Quantity 
     ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(Val ,'-','.'),1) AS PricePaid         
FROM dbo.Split(@String, '<br>')
WHERE NULLIF(val ,'') IS NOT NULL
```

### Result Set

```
╔═════════════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║      EventName      ║ AccountNumber ║ Quantity ║ PricePaid ║
╠═════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║ Education Luncheon  ║ 501-2620      ║       2  ║  $110     ║
║ Womens Breakfast    ║ 512-2620      ║       2  ║  $80      ║
║ Friday Luncheon     ║ 502-26200     ║       2  ║  110      ║
╚═════════════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: I have changed the data around a little bit to see if it still works and unless data is way out of order it works :)